# Dynamic lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have created an expression like:

```
expression = x => x.CustomerName.StartsWith(comboParams.ParamValueText, true, null);
```

I would like access customer name as generic something like this:

```
expression = x => x["CustomerName"] and access the StartsWith function
```

I have already tried code such as

```
expression x => x.GetType().GetProperty("CustomerName").Name.StartsWith(comboParams.ParamValueText, true, null); --> it doesn't seem to work :(
```

Is there a way to accomplish this task. I'm making this to have a common implementation for the expression, maybe I'll create a function for this and just accept the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `x.GetType().GetProperty("CustomerName").Name` will return the name of the property not the value of it.

You need the following code.

```
expression x => x.GetType().GetProperty("CustomerName")
                           .GetValue(x, null)
                           .ToString()
                           .StartsWith(comboParams.ParamValueText, true, null);
```

Comment: Yep, I agree that your answer is correct and more concise than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that GetProperty("CustomerName").Name will always return "CustomerName", i.e. it's the name of the property.

Try something like this instead (I've refactored it a bit to be a standalone example):

```
class Customer { public string CustomerName { get; set; } }
var customer = new Customer { CustomerName = "bob" };
Expression<Func<Customer, string, bool>> expression = (c, s) => c.GetType().GetProperty("CustomerName").GetGetMethod().Invoke(c, null).ToString().StartsWith(s, true, null);

var startsResult = expression.Compile()(customer, "b"); // returns true
startsResult = expression.Compile()(customer, "x"); // returns false
```